# How to add a counter for faces detected in this code

Tags: python, opencv

***I followed a tutorial about making a face detection program with openCV with python, but now I want to add a counter in the top left with how many faces are detected by cam***

this is the used code.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import numpy as np
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os

def detect_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet):
    (h, w) = frame.shape[:2]
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1.0, (224, 224),
        (104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

    faceNet.setInput(blob)
    detections = faceNet.forward()
    print(detections.shape)

    faces = []
        # fixed the error with variable faces...Faces ===> faces
    locs = []
    preds = []

    for i in range(0, detections.shape[2]):
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        if confidence > 0.5:
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            (startX, startY) = (max(0, startX), max(0, startY))
            (endX, endY) = (min(w - 1, endX), min(h - 1, endY))

            face = frame[startY:endY, startX:endX]
            face = cv2.cvtColor(face, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            face = cv2.resize(face, (224, 224))
            face = img_to_array(face)
            face = preprocess_input(face)

            faces.append(face)
            locs.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))

    if len(faces) > 0:
        faces = np.array(faces, dtype="float32")
        preds = maskNet.predict(faces, batch_size=32)

    return (locs, preds)

prototxtPath = r"face_detector\deploy.prototxt"
weightsPath = r"face_detector\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel"
faceNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(prototxtPath, weightsPath)

maskNet = load_model("training_model.model")

print("Starting video stream..")
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)

    (locs, preds) = detect_mask(frame, faceNet, maskNet)

    for (box, pred) in zip(locs, preds):
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box
        (mask, withoutMask) = pred

        label = "There is a mask" if mask > withoutMask else "There is no mask"
        color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "There is a mask" else (0, 0, 255)

        label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)

        cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Advanced Thanks! .....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0):

If you try to understand what tutorial trying to do, It will be very easy for you to reach your goal yourself.

Hints: Duplicate below part of the code to print counter on the frame. Just change coordinates to locate top left of the frame and also add counter variable to increment every time when confidence level is > 0

```
    label = "There is a mask" if mask > withoutMask else "There is no mask"
    color = (0, 255, 0) if label == "There is a mask" else (0, 0, 255)

    label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(label, max(mask, withoutMask) * 100)

    cv2.putText(frame, label, (startX, startY - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, color, 2)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), color, 2)
```